# An Issue with Blogger new Notable theme: thumbnail image box

Tags: image, css, thumbnails, blogger

In the home page the thumbnail image box shows the image of the post like this:
[image]

Is there anyway I can make the thumbnail image box contain the image of the post? 
It always zoom the picture in any post I make, whatever the the dimensions of the image are.
I have played a little bit with the css of this part but I couldn't get it to contain the image.

Thank you
my blog URL: www.aflamtalk.com

Answer (score 0):

You can try `background-size: contain` on the `span.snippet-thumbnail-img` selector.

Like so:

```
span.snippet-thumbnail-img {
    background-size: contain;
}
```

This may or may not be the effect you desire. It depends on your use case

Answer (score 0):

Search for the following block of code

```
.post-outer .snippet-thumbnail-img {
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

And change `background-size: cover;` to `background-size: contain;`

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution in changing:

```
background-image: url(<b:eval expr='resizeImage(data:post.featuredImage, 256, &quot;1:1&quot;).cssEscaped'/>);
```

to

```
background-image: url(<b:eval expr='resizeImage(data:post.featuredImage, 256, &quot;16:9&quot;).cssEscaped'/>);
```

in `<b:includable id='normalPost'>`